# How to give write access to a directory which is exposed to host using docker-compose volume key?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know how to expose directory inside container to host using volume key in docker-compose file

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:
  my-service:
    build: my-service
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ~/logs/my-service:/var/log/my-service
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    expose:
      - 5000
    environment:
      CONFIG_LOG_FOLDER: /var/log/my-service
```

I am running container as non-root user. Here is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ARG USER_ID=999

# Add the user (alok)
RUN groupadd -r alok && useradd --uid ${USER_ID} -r -g alok -G audio,video alok && \
  mkdir -p /home/alok/Videos && \
  chown -R alok:alok /home/alok

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN chown -R alok:alok /usr/src/app
RUN mkdir /var/log/my-service
RUN chown -R alok:alok /var/log/my-service # I want this to be writable
USER alok
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["./start.sh"]
```

I am running this setup using sudo command

```bash
sudo docker-compose up --build
```

Inside container

```bash
alok@9629484fff33:/usr/src/app$ ls -l /var/log
total 920
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root             20019 Feb 23 18:25 alternatives.log
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root              4096 Feb 23 18:24 apt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root             58592 Jan 26 08:26 bootstrap.log
-rw-rw---- 1 root utmp                 0 Jan 26 08:26 btmp
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root              4096 Nov 20 22:31 dist-upgrade
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root            449244 Feb 23 18:25 dpkg.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root             32000 Feb 23 18:25 faillog
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root              8193 Feb 23 18:24 fontconfig.log
drwxr-sr-x 2 root systemd-journal   4096 Feb 23 18:07 journal
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp            292000 Feb 23 18:25 lastlog
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root             40960 Apr 13 14:25 my-service
drwx------ 2 root root              4096 Feb 23 18:07 private
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root                 0 Feb 23 18:20 ubuntu-advantage.log
drwxr-x--- 2 root adm               4096 May 19  2022 unattended-upgrades
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root utmp                 0 Jan 26 08:26 wtmp
```

`/var/log/my-service` directory is automatically getting created because I defined `volume` key in `docker-compose` file. I want this directory to be writable by user which is defined in `Dockerfile` so I added `RUN chown -R alok:alok /var/log/my-service` but still owner is root only. So user alok is not able to write file.

How can I make `/var/log/my-service` writable by non root user which is defined in Dockerfile in setup?

Answer (score 2):

If you check the permissions for the folder in your home directly, the owner is probably root.

This is because when you bind mount a folder that doesn't exist, it'll create it for you, **but with the owner set to root**.

To mitigate that, manually create the folder as your desired user before running the compose up.

Alternatively, if you want to migrate an existing one, you can just set the permissions on the host system.

Comment: owner for home directory (/home/alok) is alok not root.

Comment: Yes, but you mounted in `~/logs/my-service`, the permissions for those folders can be different, which is most likely the case here.

Comment: I am running this setup using sudo `sudo docker-compose up --build` so owner of `~/logs/my-service` is root. So is this the reason why owner of `/var/log/my-service` is root inside container?

Comment: Exactly. The permissions of the folder on the host are the same as in the container, that's the point of bind mounts.

Comment: on ubuntu I have to run docker-compose using sudo. so is there any way container user (alok) can write to `/var/log/my-service` and container uses is not root user. you can see Dockerfile in question

Comment: Sure, just do a `chown` on the host system to give the user id and group id of the docker user access to the folder on your host.

Comment: Thanks, my problem is solved by manually running command chmod on `~/logs/my-service`. But is there any way to give write permission using `docker-compose` or `Dockerfile` file? So i can get rid of this manual step

Comment: I'm trying to come up with one because I'm commonly annoyed by this issue as well, but as of now, I unfortunately don't know of any way.